# c# -> Entity Framework -> Asp.Net Identity -> Set custom data types

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework-6, asp.net-identity

Since Entity Framework 6.1.3 uses `nvarchar(MAX)` as default for strings I wan't to change this to `nvarchar(256)` instead. You can read some more about why `nvarchar(MAX)` hurts performance on the link below. Short answer is Indexes.

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/48408/ef-code-first-uses-nvarcharmax-for-all-strings-will-this-hurt-query-performan

I have done this by adding this line to `OnModelCreating`:

```
modelBuilder.Properties<string>().Configure(s => 
    s.HasMaxLength(256).HasColumnType("nvarchar"));
```

However this also affects the columns created automatically by `IdentityDbContext` (Individual user accounts).

Specifically `dbo.AspNetUsers.PasswordHash`, `dbo.AspNetUsers.SecurityStamp`, `dbo.AspNetUserClaims.ClaimType` and `dbo.AspNetUserClaims.ClaimValue`. For these I still wan't to use `nvarchar(MAX)`.

For properties that I have access to I can use the column attribute and this will be fixed. Example:

```
[Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(MAX)")]
public string CaseComment { get; set; }
```

I guess I have to use fluent API to solve this but how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found my answer here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relational/columns

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
    .Property(b => b.PasswordHash)
    .HasColumnType("nvarchar(MAX)")
    .HasMaxLength(null);

modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
    .Property(b => b.SecurityStamp)
    .HasColumnType("nvarchar(MAX)")
    .HasMaxLength(null);

modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUserClaim>()
    .Property(b => b.ClaimType)
    .HasColumnType("nvarchar(MAX)")
    .HasMaxLength(null);

modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUserClaim>()
    .Property(b => b.ClaimValue)
    .HasColumnType("nvarchar(MAX)")
    .HasMaxLength(null);
```

`ApplicationUserClaim` is because we use custom claims in our application. The default would be:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim>()
    .Property(b => b.ClaimType)
    .HasColumnType("nvarchar(MAX)");

modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim>()
    .Property(b => b.ClaimValue)
    .HasColumnType("nvarchar(MAX)");
```

**Update 2**

Using a override for all strings like this:

```
modelBuilder.Properties<string>().Configure(s => 
    s.HasMaxLength(256).HasColumnType("nvarchar"));
```

and then modifying properties with attributes like this:

```
[Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(MAX)")]
public string CaseComment { get; set; }
```

Or this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim>()
    .Property(b => b.ClaimType)
    .HasColumnType("nvarchar(MAX)");
```

This can cause the Exception. `Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details.` Even though the column is of correct data type Entity Framework still thinks it is `nvarchar(256)` and throws the error `DbEntityValidationException`.

To fix this use the following instead:

```
[Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(MAX)")]
[MaxLength]
public string CaseComment { get; set; }

modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim>()
    .Property(b => b.ClaimType)
    .HasColumnType("nvarchar(MAX)")
    .HasMaxLength(null);
```

**Update:**

If you have a standard `ApplicationUser` and wan't to keep it as is but still wan't `nvarchar(256)` as standard you can use these settings:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
    .Property(b => b.Id)
    .HasColumnType("nvarchar")
    .HasMaxLength(128);

modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
    .Property(b => b.PasswordHash)
    .HasColumnType("nvarchar(MAX)")
    .HasMaxLength(null);

modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
    .Property(b => b.SecurityStamp)
    .HasColumnType("nvarchar(MAX)")
    .HasMaxLength(null);

modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
    .Property(b => b.PhoneNumber)
    .HasColumnType("nvarchar(MAX)")
    .HasMaxLength(null);

modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>()
    .Property(b => b.Id)
    .HasColumnType("nvarchar")
    .HasMaxLength(128);

modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>()
    .Property(b => b.UserId)
    .HasColumnType("nvarchar")
    .HasMaxLength(128);

modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>()
    .Property(b => b.RoleId)
    .HasColumnType("nvarchar")
    .HasMaxLength(128);

modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>()
    .Property(b => b.UserId)
    .HasColumnType("nvarchar")
    .HasMaxLength(128);

modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>()
    .Property(b => b.LoginProvider)
    .HasColumnType("nvarchar")
    .HasMaxLength(128);

modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>()
    .Property(b => b.ProviderKey)
    .HasColumnType("nvarchar")
    .HasMaxLength(128);

modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim>()
    .Property(b => b.UserId)
    .HasColumnType("nvarchar")
    .HasMaxLength(128);

modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim>()
    .Property(b => b.ClaimType)
    .HasColumnType("nvarchar(MAX)")
    .HasMaxLength(null);

modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim>()
    .Property(b => b.ClaimValue)
    .HasColumnType("nvarchar(MAX)")
    .HasMaxLength(null);
```